# I have difficulty using long subject

Tags: modifiers, noun-phrases

It is hard to use long noun phrase subject. I hope to make it easy to read.

For example,

> The relation between luminance and pupil area under dynamic condition
>   will be computed.

In this case, The relation ~ dynamic condition is my subject but it is too long.

Then, should I use like this?

> The relation will be computed between luminance and pupil area under dynamic condition.

It looks 'between' modifies 'computed', not 'the relation'....

I will appreciate if you teach me how to deal with such a case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes, it's acceptable to use the active voice: "We compute the relationship between..."

Comment: Apart from the fact that the phrase isn’t very idiomatic (wrong preposition, lacking plural), there’s nothing inherently wrong with your original sentence. Long subjects aren’t a problem, as long as they’re clear and easy to understand. I have no idea what exactly constitutes ‘dynamic conditions’ (whatever those are) for the ‘pupil area’ (whatever that is—do you mean the size of the pupil?), but I assume your readers will know more about this than I do. _“The relation(ship) between luminance and pupil size in dynamic conditions will be computed”_ sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: (Incidentally, I’m starting to doubt my statement that _under_ is wrong as a preposition here. _In_ sounds more natural and straightforward in my head, but thinking about it, _under_ doesn’t actually sound wrong, either. And a bit of Googling reveals lots of hits for both “in dynamic conditions” and “under dynamic conditions”. So feel free to ignore that bit.)

Comment: Thank you, Andrew Leach and Janus Bahs Jacquet. As you anticipated, it is a sentence for scientific research so it is natural that you can't understand fully without background knowledge. Your advices were helpful. Thank you again :)

Comment: It seems that the relationship between luminance and pupil area under dynamic conditions isn't something you *compute*, but something you have to discover by experiment. So I would rethink the last verb in your sentence. Maybe *"A formula is given for the relation between luminance ..."* (or *"will be"*, if you prefer the future tense).

Comment: Your original sentence is basically correct and not all that awkward.  The most glaring problem is that you say "under dynamic condition" rather than "under dynamic conditions" or some other equivalent phrase.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this can be done in your case, but if possible, you may describe or define a long subject in one sentence then use a clear and simple name for the whole subject in following sentences.

"The relationship between X and Y is such and such". We will compute *this relationship*... "

"We are studying such and such a relation. *This relation* will be computed..."

Comment: Thank you, borbo. It was helpful, although I wish to write it with a single sentence.